# How made Unity to open its windows on correct display

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen

I have really annoying problem, I have laptop and one extra monitor, my laptop screen is my main display and I want to keep it as it is. I'm opening Unity on my second screen and when I open some of unity window like 'Profiler', 'Animator', 'Preferences..' etc or any other window then it displays on my laptop screen and not where unity is actually opened and I have to move it each time manually to my second screen ; O I didn't observe such behaviour for any other apps. Does anyone have idea how I can fix that ?! I would be very veryy grateful for help!

I'm using Windows 10.

Here you have professional visualisation ;D

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling that Unity3D opens those on the 'main' monitor. If you switch your main screen to your monitor, does Unity3D open in that one now? It might be how Unity3D registers new windows. SQL Server Management Studio does the same thing to me with a filter window.

Comment: Yeah, when I set my external monitor as main display unity3d works as it should but it's not satisfying solution because then all other apps open on external monitor as well ... Did you figured some solution with this filter window ? It's realy pissing me off because when I'm watching some video-tutorial on my laptop screen and open any window in Unity then focus is set to opened window and video go to background ... ; /

Comment: I don't think that is something you can control .. a lot of programs do that actually and it's just how things are.. you can however place your windows how you want them and save the current Layout. Than you can switch between layouts and unity will again place your windows on the correct screens

Comment: so i was playing around with this. once i loaded a layout on one screen, it  opened windows on that screen. if i just moved the main window to the other screen, and reopened the secondary window(i used the animation window) it showed up on the original scree. if i then cloased the animator, and set the layout to 2 by 3, when i reopened the animator it was on the correct screen. so i would say set the windows how you want them, save that layout. then reload that layout. it should make that the active monitor for the session.

Comment: @PrinceOfRavens I have checked what you proposed but it didn't work for me ;< I tried something like this: I moved window (e.g. 'Animation' window) from main display to display where Unity is open and then each next time I opened that window it opens on the correct screen, it not works for all of the windows e.g. "Preferences..." - this window always open on main screen in my case